# Setting the size of a Gmail-addon GUI

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-addons

I didn't see any way to change the dimensions of a Gmail-addon GUI. 
Is there an option to set the width and height of a Gmail-Addon app?

Comment: You should specify the UI you are currently using, and include examples of your existing UI, and what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Do you want to change the size of the sidebar of Gmail add-on? If my understanding is correct, unfortunately, I think that it cannot be achieved. Because by [updating February 18, 2014](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/releases/2014#february_2014), this modification ``they cannot be changed from the default width of 300px.`` was added. Although this is for Spreadsheet, I think that applications which use the sidebars are also the same. I have tried to change the size of sidebar for Gmail add-on. But it couldn't do.